# Transposed Array from array

Tags: r

Let `A[ , , ]` be an `array` of dimension `[2,3,4]`

For example,

```
A <- array(1:24,c(2,3,4))
```

I want to get a new array `B` of dimension `[2,4,3]` such that

```
B[i,j,k]=A[i,k,j]
```

for all `i,j,k`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `aperm`:

```
aperm(A, c(1, 3, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you, I am always surprised very quick response, and  very brief plain answer. Since it belongs to package  `base`, it helps me very much. Thank you.